# Numpy offset values across dimensions, starting from smallest

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 3D array arr of dimension (2,4,500). Looking at arr[..., 0], the sub-array looks as follows:

```
array([[ 700,    0, 2000,    0],
       [-400,    0,    0, -200]])
```

I can guarantee that for a given row of this sub-array either all values will be non-negative, or non-positive (i.e we won't have a positive and a negative value in the same row).

What I'm trying to achieve is to offset the two rows against each other regardless of the position, such that the smallest (in absolute terms) entry will be reduced first. For the above example, the desired output array is:

```
array([[ 100,    0, 2000,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0]])
```

I.e. I can first offset the -200 against the 700, and then the -400 against the remaining 500.

In another example:

```
array([[ 100,    0, 2000,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0, -200]])
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
array([[   0,    0, 1900,    0],
       [   0,    0,    0,    0]])
```

If the entries of both rows have the same sign (e.g. swapping the -200 for a 200 in the above example) then the array should be kept as is. Ideally this could be directly applied to the 3D array, but I'm also happy to loop over the 2D sub-arrays of dimension (2,4) if necessary.

My feeling is that a neat solution must exist, possibly based on cumsum and argsort, but I have been unable to make it work.

Edit:
The termination criterion for each sub-array is either immediately (if the sum of both rows has the same sign or is 0), or once one of the rows becomes zero.

The below code example should hopefully highlight what I am trying to achieve:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[-700, 0, -2000, 0], [400, 0, 0, 200]])

out_arr = np.zeros_like(arr)
row0sum = np.nansum(arr[0])
row1sum = np.nansum(arr[1])
if np.sign(row0sum) * np.sign(row1sum) == -1:
    if abs(row0sum) > abs(row1sum):
        non_zeroing_index = 0
        zeroing_index = 1
    else:
        non_zeroing_index = 1
        zeroing_index = 0
    size_order = np.argsort(abs(arr[non_zeroing_index]))
    total_reducing_value = np.nansum(arr[zeroing_index])
    for i, val in enumerate(arr[non_zeroing_index][size_order]):
        if total_reducing_value == 0:
            out_arr[non_zeroing_index, size_order[i]] = val
        if val == 0:
            continue
        elif val > 0:
            resulting_value = np.clip(val + total_reducing_value, 0, val)
            reduction = resulting_value - val
            out_arr[non_zeroing_index, size_order[i]] = resulting_value
            total_reducing_value -= reduction
        else:
            resulting_value = np.clip(val + total_reducing_value, val, 0)
            reduction = resulting_value - val
            out_arr[non_zeroing_index, size_order[i]] = resulting_value
            total_reducing_value -= reduction
else:
    out_arr = arr
# move on to the next sub array
```

However, iterating over each sub-array is bound to be slow, especially if this has to be done hundreds of times

Comment: It's not clear to me what the process is and when you know to stop. Can you please share more examples and include a looping code that does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could write an offset function to carry out the task in all the matrices:

```
import numpy as np

def offset(x):
  z = x.copy()
  sm = -z[:,1].sum(1)
  cmsm = z[:,0].cumsum(1)
  bool_idx = cmsm >= sm[:,None]
  
  s = np.where(bool_idx)
  mat, ind_index = np.unique(s[0], return_counts = True)
  idx = np.minimum.reduceat(s[1], np.r_[0,ind_index.cumsum()[:-1]])
  z[:,0][~bool_idx] = 0
  z[mat, 0, idx] = cmsm[mat, idx] - sm
  z[:,1] = 0
  return z
```

---

```
a = np.array([[ 700,    0, 2000,    0], [-400,    0,    0, -200]])
b = np.array([[ 100,    0, 2000,    0], [   0,    0,    0, -200]])

full_array = np.array([a, b]) # You need a 3 dimensional array to pass to the function

offset(full_array)
array([[[ 100,    0, 2000,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]],

       [[   0,    0, 1900,    0],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0]]])
```

### Edit

In the case where you have larger negatives, use the function below:

```
def multi_offset(x):
  z = x.copy()
  index = z.sum((1,2)) >= 0
  z[index] = offset(z[index])
  z[~index] = -offset(-z[~index][:,::-1,:])[:,::-1,:]
  return z

c = np.array([[400, 0, 0, 200], [-700, 0, -2000, 0]])
multi_offset(np.array([a, b, c]))
array([[[  100,     0,  2000,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0,     0]],

       [[    0,     0,  1900,     0],
        [    0,     0,     0,     0]],

       [[    0,     0,     0,     0],
        [ -100,     0, -2000,     0]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems to work in the case of 2 arrays. But if I add a third array `c = np.array([[400, 0, 0, 200], [-700, 0, -2000, 0]])` then I run into shape issues, regardless of whether I define full_array as `full_array = np.array([a, b, c|])`, leading to shape (3,2,4) or `full_array = np.concatenate((a[..., np.newaxis], b[..., np.newaxis], c[..., np.newaxis]), axis=-1)`, leading to shape (2,4,3).

Comment: @Exclusive92 Notice that this is an edge case. You didnot specify what should happen in the case that the positives are unable to completely offset the negatives. I did not take this into account. Try will all cases where by the positives are greater than the negatives

Comment: @Exclusive92 in a scenario where the negatives cannot be fully offset against the positives. What should happen? Once you answer that, you can incorporate the logic to the function

Comment: In that case I'd want to apply the same logic, i.e. start moving the least negative value to 0, then the next etc. So in my array c the result should be `np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [-100, 0, -2000, 0]])`. In which case flipping the signs inside your function s.t. the positives can always offset the negatives, and then flipping back as desired should do it?

Comment: @Exclusive92 That will be different. The logic i used so far is assuming all the positives are above the negatives, and I am offseting the negatives against the positives knowing that the negatives will go to zero. I will have to think on that. You should probably consider dividing your array into 2 parts. Those that satisfy the status above, and those that do not. ie `idx=my_array.sum((1,2)) >=0`. For those that satisfy, run the function above ie my_array[idx]. For those that do not, run the function on the negation of the inverted array. Check update

Comment: @Exclusive92 also how is -700 the "least negative value"?